# Servlet filters not working properly

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

I have a login.java servlet, from where after taking the username and password, if correct, we are directed to welcome.java servlet.A filter named loginfilter.java verifies the username and password. If the username and password are not correct, i have an errorpage.java servlet which is then called.

My filter is not working which i dont know why. i think my web.xml code and filters code are correct. Plz help me find out the error.

Here is the code for my filter

```
package filters;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class loginfilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain
    chain throws IOException, ServletException     {
           String u=request.getParameter("username");
           String p=request.getParameter("password");
           String user="akshay";
           String pass="akshay";
           if (u.equals(user) && p.equals(pass)){
               chain.doFilter(request,response);
           }        
     }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    private RequestDispatcher getReuestDispatcher(String loginpage) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Here is the code for web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>welcomepage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>welcomepage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>errorpage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>errorpage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errorpage</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/errorpage</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
        <location>/errorpage</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.io.IOException</exception-type>
        <location>/errorpage</location>
    </error-page>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>loginfilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filters.loginfilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>loginfilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>welcomepage</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>welcomepage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcomepage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>errorpage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/errorpage</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: not working is not an appropriate description of any issue. Tell us exactly what is the problem. How is it not working?

Comment: `request.getParameter()` returns null if there is no such parameter. You will get an NPE in your case.

Comment: Filter not calling ?? or Code in filter behaving not  as expected ??

Comment: A filter isn't an appropriate place to check login credentials anyway.

Comment: I am using netbeans. it says BUILD FAILED. I just want that if the the entered username and password are incorrect, er get directed to the errorpage servlet. how can i accomplish that??

Comment: @Dave Newton
What would be better for my web application? Should i define another servlet to check the login credentials or use filter??

Comment: Logging in is a single-point process; IMO it should be a servlet. Filters are for wide-reaching functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the lines with:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

These lines prevent the filter is initialized, and also stops the application.

> The server calls `init(FilterConfig)` once to prepare the filter for service, then calls `doFilter()` any number of times for requests specially set up to use the filter. The `FilterConfig` interface has methods to retrieve the filter's name, its init parameters, and the active servlet context. The server calls `destroy()` to indicate that the filter is being taken out of service.

*http://www.servlets.com/soapbox/filters.html*

Comment: @user1869756 You will likely need to diagnose why the *build* is failing; it doesn't even sound like your app is compiling and/or deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing exception in `init` method is not valid
It will stop the initialization of the filter.
Remove below line

```
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```